# Нужно создать функцию (kick_all) для discord бота на языке Python, которая будет кикать всех с сервера

Tags: python, discord, discord-api, discord.py

Вот моя функция кика опред. участника

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await ctx.channel.purge()
    await member.kick(reason = reason)
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `for i in guild.members`, и кикайте при помощи `await i.kick()`.